# Set a default value inside an input box, crud application using spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, forms, crud

I'm trying to make a CRUD application using Spring MVC, but whenever I click the edit button to update an entry in a row, my jsp page to edit an entry (wizardeditform.jsp) has the 'designation' and 'wand' inputs filled in from that entry with the correct values. I would like all the input boxes to have the default values from that row, not just the 'wand' and 'designation' input boxes. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? (Ive been following this tutorial: http://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-crud-example)

wizardeditform.jsp

```
<h1>Edit Witch or Wizard</h1>
<form:form method="POST" action="/WizardingWorld/editsave">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><form:hidden path="id" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First name :</td>
            <td><form:input path="firstname"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last name :</td>
            <td><form:input path="lastname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Designation :</td>
            <td><form:input path="designation"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>School and house :</td>
            <td><form:input path="schoolAndHouse" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>wand :</td>
            <td><form:input path="wand" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Blood Type</td>
            <td><form:input path="bloodtype" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

Controller class

```
// displays form to input data, "command" is request attr. used to display
// object data into form
@RequestMapping("/wizardform")
public ModelAndView showform() {
    return new ModelAndView("wizardform", "command", new Wizard());
}

// saves object into database. The @ModelAttribute puts request data into
// model object.
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute("wizard") Wizard wizard) {
    dao.save(wizard);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/viewwizard");// will redirect to
                                                    // viewwizard request
                                                    // mapping
}

// provides list of employees in model object
@RequestMapping("/viewwizard")
public ModelAndView viewwizard() {
    List<Wizard> list = dao.getWizards();
    return new ModelAndView("viewwizard", "list", list);
}

// It displays object data into form for the given id. The @PathVariable
// puts URL data into variable
@RequestMapping(value = "/editwizard/{id}")
public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable int id) {
    Wizard wizard = dao.getWizardById(id);
    return new ModelAndView("wizardeditform", "command", wizard);
}

// updates model object
@RequestMapping(value = "/editsave", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView editsave(@ModelAttribute("wizard") Wizard wizard) {
    dao.update(wizard);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/viewwizard");
}
```

The first image is the jsp page to view all the table entries, and the second image is is the wizardeditform.jsp , right after clicking the edit button on the previous page with all the entries.

[image: this is the jsp page to view all the entries]

[image: this is the wizardeditform.jsp , right after clicking the edit button on the previous page]

Comment: Are there any error message in your console?

Comment: No, there are not @Sky